# Alexa Conversation: Converting from a Variable to an API Parameter?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm new to Alexa Conversations - still learning. My challenge: In the Alexa Conversation Dialog, I'm trying to enable a skill to ask to play music in a certain room. For example, a user might ask to play Prince in the Kitchen or they might ask to play Let's Go Crazy in the Bedroom or they might ask to play Dua Lipa Radio in the Bathroom. In each case, I need to prompt the user to ask them if the request is an Artist, a Song, a Playlist or a Station.  Currently I'm prompting the user and saving their answer in a custom variable called MusicType.

[image]

How do I now take the answer and convert that to a different API Parameter? In this case I'd want to take MusicType and set it to PlayListName in the API.  I don't see how to take the values out of variables and then associate them to something else. help?

I tried using the Inform Args section but that will only continue to save the variable - it seems it needs conditional logic here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the [Alexa Conversations Description Language](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/conversations/acdl-get-started.html) you can add [conditional logic](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/conversations/acdl-conditional-expressions.html) as already suggested by yourself, which then uses further [expressions](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/conversations/acdl-expressions.html) to handle the variable content and/or invoke the API in different ways.

But be aware that the feature is currently in Beta (might change without notice) and is not supported in the UI, so it needs to be done with [CLI access](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/conversations/acdl-set-up-ask-cli.html) from your side.